# mysql unique hash index's value was written into binlog

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table using unique hash index, it has 15 columns. But the binlog row shows a extra LONGINT field containing a very large value. It seems that unique "hash index" in mariadb 10.4.18 instances would cause the problem.

table:

```
CREATE TABLE `xxxx` (
`release_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`release_seq_no` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
......
`modify_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`release_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `index_release_seq_no` USING HASH (`release_seq_no`)) 
ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 321206 CHARSET = utf8
```

binlog:

```
#Write_rows: table id 58002 flags: STMT_END_F
### INSERT INTO `xxx`.`xxxx`
### SET
###   @1=2328410 /* INT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
......
###   @15='2023-10-30 10:01:03' /* DATETIME(0) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @16=6755689043813728036 /* LONGINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
# Number of rows: 1
```

What mechanism in InnoDB causes this problem to occur? This mechanism causes abnormality in my CDC function.

Comment: I tested your example using MySQL 8.2.0, but I don't see a LONGINT at the end of the binlog event. Perhaps this is a MariaDB behavior. You should make clear exactly which brand and version you are using. MySQL and MariaDB are different products, and an answer for one may not be relevant for the other.

Comment: thank you, I have reproduced this issue in several versions(10.4/10.5) that I have used, but some instances of the same version do not have this issue. I'm not sure what parameter(s) may be different.

Comment: 10.4/10.5? 10.4 has 31 different releases, 10.5 has 22 different releases. The version of mysqlbinlog used is also missing. To check if it is a bug in write_rows event or in mysqldump itself you should also provide the table_map event and the encoded write_rows event (running mysqldump without options -v and  --base64-output=DECODE_ROWS).

Answer (score 0):

From mariadb 10.4 on, the unique HASH index would generate a invisible DB_ROW_HASH_1 column at POS 65551, and the binlog also record the value for the extra column.
CDC tool has to support the feature, or we can keep using BTREE index.

information_schema.INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS:

```
+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------+---------+-----+
| tname   | ROW_FORMAT | TABLE_ID | NAME           | POS   | MTYPE | PRTYPE  | LEN |
+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------+---------+-----+
| svca/t1 | Dynamic    |     7984 | release_id     |     0 |     6 |    1283 |   4 |
......
| svca/t1 | Dynamic    |     7984 | release_seq_no |     5 |    12 | 2162703 |  96 |
......
| svca/t1 | Dynamic    |     7984 | modify_time    |    14 |     3 |  525324 |   5 |
| svca/t1 | Dynamic    |     7984 | DB_ROW_HASH_1  | 65551 |     6 |    9736 |   8 |
```